# Change common color in ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, triggers, controltemplate

I have a ControlTemplate which uses the same color in multiple elements. On certain triggers (e.g. OnMouseOver) I'd like to change that color. As far as I can see I have to define a setter for every element to change its color. Is there a way to reference a shared resource in the template that all contained elements can access, and which can be changed by a trigger, so I don't have to address each and every element?

Here's an (made up) example:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="myTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Ellipse Fill="red" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <Ellipse Fill="red" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
 </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

When the control is disabled, I want the ellipses to be grey, **without setting both of them explicitly**, e.g. I **don't** want to write

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
  <Setter TargetName="_ellipse1" Property="Fill" Value="Grey"/>
  <Setter TargetName="_ellipse2" Property="Fill" Value="Grey"/>
</Trigger>
```

but set the color of both ellipses with just **one** setter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the trigger on a style for the ellipses (ellipsi?) instead of the button. IsEnabled will propagate down if you set IsEnabled = false on the Button.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="myTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Ellipse Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Ellipse Grid.Column="1"/>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: That did the trick in the simplest way, thanks.
(though I had to figure out that you must not define the color in ControlTemplate, but in the style exclusively.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is with a value converter. Then you can avoid a messy trigger altogether. Here is your example, but with a converter added.

```
<Window.Resources>
  <local:EnabledToColorConverter x:Key="enabledToColorConverter"/>
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="myTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Ellipse Name="_ellipse1" Fill="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource enabledToColorConverter}}" Grid.Column="0"/>
      <Ellipse Name="_ellipse2" Fill="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource enabledToColorConverter}}" Grid.Column="1"/>
      <ContentPresenter Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
  </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
  <Button Template="{StaticResource myTemplate}">Enabled Button</Button>
  <Button Template="{StaticResource myTemplate}" IsEnabled="False">Disabled Button</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

And here is the converter:

```
public class EnabledToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool isEnabled = (bool)value;
        return isEnabled ?
            Brushes.Red :
            Brushes.Gray;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's pretty ugly solution, because the colors are hard-coded in the value converter (unfortunately, IValueConverter.Convert takes only one parameter), but that could do the trick. I'll try that.

Comment: No, you could use ConverterParameter on the binding and pass different colors. Or you could define the colors statically and access them that way.